# property values of entities in table storage accessed through C# are zero

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I have a table storage that stores deviceid, timestamp and pm1. I try to use C# to access entities that have certain device id and between certain time range. I was able to get the entities I want but the pm1 readings for these entities are zeros which are not correct. The pm1 readings are not missing in table storage. how can i solve this?

Here is my code:

```
main():
    string partitionFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("deviceid", QueryComparisons.Equal, StartEntity.deviceid);
            string date1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("ts", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,starttime);
            string date2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("ts", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, endtime);
            string datefilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(date1, TableOperators.And, date2);
            string pm1con = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("pm1con", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, 0);
            string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionFilter,TableOperators.And, datefilter);
            string extrafilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(finalFilter, TableOperators.And, pm1con);
            TableQuery<EventEntity> RangeQueryforEnentEntities = new TableQuery<EventEntity>().Where(extrafilter);
            TableContinuationToken token = null;

            do
            {
                TableQuerySegment<EventEntity> resultSegment = EventsTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented(RangeQueryforEnentEntities, token);
                token = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

                foreach (EventEntity entity in resultSegment.Results)
                {
                    EventEntities.Add(entity);
                    log.Info($"C# All the entities in current event: {entity.deviceid}, {entity.ts}, {entity.PM1Con}");
                }

            } while (token != null);

            return EventEntities; 

public class EventEntity : TableEntity
{
    public EventEntity(string deviceid, DateTime ts, int PM1Con, float TumblingB_threshold, float TumblingB_confidence)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = deviceid;
        this.RowKey = ts.ToLongDateString();
    }

    public EventEntity() { }

    public string deviceid { get; set; }

    public DateTime ts { get; set; }

    public float pm1con { get; set; }

    public float TumblingB_threshold { get; set; }

    public float TumblingB_confidence { get; set; }

}
```

here is the returned result:

```
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 2:42:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 2:45:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 2:51:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 2:54:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 2:57:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:00:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:03:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:06:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:09:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:12:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:15:00 AM, 0
[2017-11-08 5:25:59 PM] C# All the entities in current event: HAVEN-0D0E0A-TZ-000115, 2017-10-25 3:18:00 AM, 0
```

Here is the result i want:
[image]

So as you can see the return pm1con values are wrong.

Comment: Please share part of your source code for troubleshooting, I don't think the description is sufficient for locating the problem.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft The question is edited. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about data type. I used float as pm1con data type but I should use double.

Comment: Yes, float is not supported in Azure Storage Table.

Comment: does it supported decimal? this is confusing.

Comment: It's not confusing, you can find all the supported data types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model

Answer (score 0):

Instead of entity.PM1Con use entity.pm1con.

The table entity conversion is kind of case sensitive.

Comment: I change to pm1con but it does not change anything.But thank

Comment: One question is that in streaming analytics my field name is PM1Con but in azure storage explore it shows pm1con. which one should i use in my c# function.